# How to reset password without old password in Light OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, reset-password

I am using Light OAuth2 to manage authentication and I need a way to reset the password without having the old password, for example by sending a link to the user's email. This feature exists in the React Login View as a component called "Forgot Password" for the Light Portal but the Light Portal repo has been deleted so I can't see how it works.

This method presented in the "User Management" section of the tutorial requires the old password to reset the password:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"password":"123456","newPassword":"stevehu","newPasswordConfirm":"stevehu"}' https://localhost:6885/oauth2/password/stevehu
```

How can I reset the user's password without having the old password?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to reset the password by deleting the user and registering again.